# Deleted question showing in the review queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, review-queue

I was going through the "First Posts" review queue and stumbled upon this:

> https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/368555

However, when I clicked the link to view [the question itself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566871/unable-to-open-github-com-on-firefox), I discovered that it was a deleted question. Not only was it deleted, but the deletion had taken place **over 10 days ago**.

I assume this is a bug. There is no need for us to review questions that have already been deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Were you looking at the recently reviewed?

> **Review audit passed 54 mins ago:**
>    Adaephon reviewed this 54 mins ago: Reviewed

It was an audit post. They're commonly already nuked.

Comment: Ah, silly me. Yup, that would explain it.